# Node.js sharing cookies between request and selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, cookies

I am trying to login and scrape java heavy websites. I ended up using selenium on Node.js. I am able to login and see that I am logged in on the browser that gets opened by selenium. Since selenium does not have methods to access the response stream, I am trying to get it through Node.js request. I need to be able to pass my cookies through request in order to maintain my login. I am not sure if I am doing it correct since the response I get from request shows I am not logged in. Below is portion of my code:

```
   var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true});
   const driver = new Builder()
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .build();

  //perform login steps

   driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
       cookiesAll = cookies;
   });

   function onRequest(req, res) {
       var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
       if (queryData.url) {
           request({
                url: queryData.url,
                jar: cookiesAll
           }).on('error', function(e) {
                res.end(e);
           }).pipe(res);
        }
        else {
           res.end("no url found");
        }
   }
```

I checked the content of cookies all on console and it is like below:

```
   [ { domain: '.XXXX.com',
       expiry: XXXXX,
       httpOnly: false,
       name: 'djcs_kli',
       path: '/',
       secure: false,
       value: '1' },
     { domain: '.XXXX.com',
       expiry: XXXXX,
       httpOnly: false,
       name: 'XXXXX',
       path: '/',
       secure: false,
       value: 'XXXXXXX' },
     { domain: '.XXX.com',
       httpOnly: false,
       name: 's_cc',
       path: '/',
       secure: false,
       value: 'true' }]
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue? Your question is still unclear

Comment: Yes, I am not able to properly pass the cookies to request and access the restricted url. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?